# CVAT Upload YOLO annotations

Tags: yolo, cvat

Hey I am using cvat free tier and I am trying to upload yolo 1.1 annotations for the first time through the task section IN BROWSER.
I tried to follow this file format
https://opencv.github.io/cvat/docs/manual/advanced/formats/format-yolo/#yolo-export

But I am confused on a few things:
What are the file paths for images  supposed to be if the images is not in the zip?
Am i using correct file paths?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oIhZ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjWzI.png)

Can anyone help?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWHIR.png)